# shapeless HList mapping

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist

I try

```
import shapeless._
val ilist = List(1,2,3) ; 
val slist = List("a", "b", "c") ; 
(ilist :: slist :: HNil).map(list: List[_] => list -> list.length)
```

and compiler says that it needs argument type in the map function or it cannot find `list` value when type `List[_]` is provided. Is there a simple example of mapping?

There is no such problem with plain Scala lists

```
    val list1 = 1 :: 2 :: Nil; val list2 = 3 :: 4 :: Nil
    (list1 :: list2 :: Nil) map {list => list -> list.length}
```

compiles fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a no shapeless expert, but I'm sure you can do that with `~>>`. The thing is that `map` accepts `Poly`, so you need a `Poly` function that returns a constant. This is what `~>>` is.

```
  import shapeless._
  import poly._
  val ilist = List(1,2,3) ;
  val slist = List("a", "b", "c") ;

  object fun extends (List ~>> Int) {
    override def apply[T](f: List[T]): Int = f.size
  }

  println((ilist :: slist :: HNil).map(fun))
```

Note, that `~>>` is actually:

```
type ~>>[F[_], R] = ~>[F, Const[R]#λ]
```

Comment: What if I want to map `HList[String -> F[_]]`? The innocent conversion `fun(List ~>> Int) => fun((String -> List) ~>> Int)` is rejected by the compiler.

Comment: @ValentinTihomirov Not sure I've understood you correctly, but you should extend `PolyN` for more complex scenarious. See https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#polymorphic-function-values, the end of paragraph, where `object size` is defined